# Configuration for downloading large DIME attachments via C# DLL from JasperServer web service

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-2, download, jasperserver

I'm building a MVC2 .Net web app to download and view reports stored on Jasperserver.  I've built a web service client library to access the Jasperserver web service. Jasper works with DIME attachments so I'm using Microsoft.Web.Services2.

My MVC2 app works fine with smaller reports but when I try and pull down a 90 page report in html (~9mb) I run into this error:

```
WSE352: The size of the record exceed its limit.
```

The post [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/511399-wse352-size-record-exceed-its-limit) shows the following for app.config settings of my client app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
           <section name="microsoft.web.services2" type="Microsoft.Web.Services2.Configuration.WebSer vicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        ...
    </applicationSettings>
  <microsoft.web.services2>
    <messaging>
      <maxRequestLength>-1</maxRequestLength>
    </messaging>
  </microsoft.web.services2>
</configuration>
```

After making these changes I'm still running into the same error "WSE352".  My question is should the above app.config changes to my library be sufficient for my MVC app to download large reports?  Or do I need to make changes to the web.config of my MVC app?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need to add configurations to the web.config of your MVC app!

After re-reading the linked post and doing some experiments my problems where mostly copy/paste related.

Here is the relevent parts of the app.config in my library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>        
        <section name="microsoft.web.services2" type="Microsoft.Web.Services2.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
  <microsoft.web.services2>
    <messaging>
      <maxRequestLength>-1</maxRequestLength>
    </messaging>
  </microsoft.web.services2>
</configuration>
```

And the relevant parts of web.config of the MVC app:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="microsoft.web.services2" type="Microsoft.Web.Services2.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </configSections>

      <microsoft.web.services2>
        <messaging>
          <maxRequestLength>-1</maxRequestLength>
        </messaging>
      </microsoft.web.services2>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: This really halped me out, thanks!  It was the configSections I was missing, and the assembly version has to match what you are using.

Comment: @AresAvatar glad someone has found this useful!